# Get Total Sum with User Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Table:

```
UserId ReportsRead
  1        4
  2        6
  3        5
```

I would like to query that table so that I can get the following out:

```
UserId ReportsRead TotalReports
   1       4           15
```

The problem is that because I apply the WHERE clause the sum I get will be the same as users reports read.

```
SELECT UserId, ReportsRead, SUM(ReportsRead) AS TotalReports FROM MyTable WHERE UserId = 1
```

Is there a built in function that will allow me to do this? I would like to avoid Sub-queries entirely.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid a subquery here? You're only selecting one row, so any subquery you run, regardless of complexity, is only going to run once anyway.

Comment: @ZLK Yes, the "MyTable" is actually a rather long subquery that I do not want to run twice. I presented it here as my table to try and keep things simple.

Comment: In that case, you might want to incorporate the idea of the `SUM() OVER()` window function that is suggested in the answers into your long subquery such that you're just selecting an additional column, assuming you only want to select one column at the very end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't usually recommend subqueries in this situation, but in this case, it seems like a simple approach:

```
SELECT UserId, ReportsRead,
       (SELECT SUM(ReportsRead) from MyTable) AS TotalReports
FROM MyTable
WHERE UserId = 1;
```

If you want rows for *all* users, then window functions are the way to go:

```
select t.*, sum(reportsread) over () as totalreports
from mytable;
```

However, you can't include a `where` clause and still expect to get the correct total.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sum` window function.

```
SELECT UserId, ReportsRead, SUM(ReportsRead) OVER() AS TotalReports 
FROM MyTable
```

Use a filtering condition to get a specific userId like

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT UserId, ReportsRead, SUM(ReportsRead) OVER() AS TotalReports 
      FROM MyTable
     ) t
WHERE UserId=1
```